# Phone keeps restarting while system updating

Tags: updates, samsung, system

My samsung galaxy core 2 got a system update so I installed it. Eventually it kept going to 90% until it said error and then restarted the whole process. It kept doing the same thing get to 90% say error and restart and continue the cycle. I cant even use my phone anymore. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try a factory rest, and install the update again.

**How to Enter Recovery Mode on Galaxy Core 2 and how to do a Factory Reset**

1) Take your phone and turn it off.

2) From your smartphone press and hold (at the same time) the power, volume up and home buttons for a few seconds.
Recovery mode should be eventually displayed on your Galaxy Core 2.
[image: Hold buttons]

3) Release held keys when the Samsung Logo appears on the screen
Then select from Recovery Mode menu "wipe data / factory reset" using Volume buttons to navigate and Power button to confirm.

[image: Wipe data/factory rest]

4) Choose "Yes -- delete all user data" to confirm the whole operation.

[image: yes]

5) You can return to Android by selecting “Reboot system now”.

[image: reboot]

*Images used are not mine but are taken from this [webpage](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-g355h-galaxy-core-ii/)*

Comment: It always opens into the system update page instead

Comment: Are you sure your in recovery mode?